# Visible Lines/Underscores on Vim

Tags: vim

I have these lines or underscores I am trying to remove on vim text editor:

[image: vim background]

The horizontal lines disappear when there is some text or code on a line.

Please let me know if you came across this before! Thanks.

Here is my .vimrc:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
" The default plugin directory will be as follows:
"   - Vim (Linux/macOS): '~/.vim/plugged'
"   - Vim (Windows): '~/vimfiles/plugged'
"   - Neovim (Linux/macOS/Windows): stdpath('data') . '/plugged'
" You can specify a custom plugin directory by passing it as the argument
"   - e.g. `call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')`
"   - Avoid using standard Vim directory names like 'plugin'

" Make sure you use single quotes



Plug 'nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter', {'do': ':TSUpdate'}


" Shorthand notation; fetches https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align
Plug 'junegunn/vim-easy-align'

" Any valid git URL is allowed
Plug 'https://github.com/junegunn/vim-github-dashboard.git'

" Multiple Plug commands can be written in a single line using | separators
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips' | Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'

" On-demand loading
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on':  'NERDTreeToggle' }
Plug 'tpope/vim-fireplace', { 'for': 'clojure' }

" Using a non-default branch
Plug 'rdnetto/YCM-Generator', { 'branch': 'stable' }

" Using a tagged release; wildcard allowed (requires git 1.9.2 or above)
Plug 'fatih/vim-go', { 'tag': '*' }

" Plugin options
Plug 'nsf/gocode', { 'tag': 'v.20150303', 'rtp': 'vim' }

" Plugin outside ~/.vim/plugged with post-update hook
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'dir': '~/.fzf', 'do': './install --all' }

" Unmanaged plugin (manually installed and updated)
Plug '~/my-prototype-plugin'

" Initialize plugin system
" - Automatically executes `filetype plugin indent on` and `syntax enable`.
call plug#end()
" You can revert the settings after the call like so:
"   filetype indent off   " Disable file-type-specific indentation
"   syntax off            " Disable syntax highlighting



Plug 'crispybaccoon/dawn.vim'

set background=dark
colorscheme dawn



" Access full color space
if (has("termguicolors"))
  set termguicolors
endif



" sometimes fixes problems on some terminals
set t_Co=256

" Disable compatibility with vi which can cause unexpected issues.
set nocompatible

" Enable type file detection. Vim will be able to try to detect the type of file in use.
filetype on

" Enable plugins and load plugin for the detected file type.
filetype plugin on

" Load an indent file for the detected file type.
filetype indent on

" Turn syntax highlighting on.
syntax on

" Add numbers to each line on the left-hand side.
set number

" Highlight cursor line underneath the cursor horizontally.
"set cursorline

" Highlight cursor line underneath the cursor vertically.
"set cursorcolumn

" Set shift width to 4 spaces.
set shiftwidth=4

" Set tab width to 4 columns.
set tabstop=4

" Use space characters instead of tabs.
set expandtab

" Do not save backup files.
set nobackup

" Do not let cursor scroll below or above N number of lines when scrolling.
set scrolloff=10

" Do not wrap lines. Allow long lines to extend as far as the line goes.
set nowrap

" While searching though a file incrementally highlight matching characters as you type.
set incsearch

" Ignore capital letters during search.
set ignorecase

" Override the ignorecase option if searching for capital letters.
" This will allow you to search specifically for capital letters.
set smartcase

" Show partial command you type in the last line of the screen.
set showcmd

" Show the mode you are on the last line.
set showmode

" Show matching words during a search.
set showmatch

" Use highlighting when doing a search.
set hlsearch

" Set the commands to save in history default number is 20.
set history=1000

" Enable auto completion menu after pressing TAB.
set wildmenu

" Make wildmenu behave like similar to Bash completion.
set wildmode=list:longest

" There are certain files that we would never want to edit with Vim.
" Wildmenu will ignore files with these extensions.
set wildignore=*.docx,*.jpg,*.png,*.gif,*.pdf,*.pyc,*.exe,*.flv,*.img,*.xlsx
```

I have been trying to customize my vim text editor. I also have tried to install plugins for different themes. I tried using tree-sitter as well but that is not really working for me right now.

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.vim` (or just rename it); then start from scratch and see which configuration change/plugin introduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

seems like the line
`colorscheme dawn`
was the one causing this issue.

i have contacted the theme creator and posted the issue on the github repository that i got it from. thanks guys!